# Google Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

i am trying to install Plugin for Eclipse  from site
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/download.html  using this site

```
http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/download.html  i have choose this  one
http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.6-Eclipse 3.6 (Helios)    according to these  rules
http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-3.6.html    but when i  put link
```

in the given location or new-install new software there is two choices  sdk  and plugin i chooses first  both  but i does not work then  each other but neither of this two works it says does not find one or more given item please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You install the Google Plugin for Eclipse using the Eclipse Install New Software process.

Here are the **[instructions](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-3.6.html)**, provided by Google, for adding the Google download link to Eclipse.